# $N$ is $(0)$ if $p(x)$ is not divisible by the square of any polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to show that in the ring $R=\frac{F[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle}$, the set of nilpotent elements, $N$ is $(0)$ iff $p(x)$ is not divisible by the square of some polynomial $q(x) \in F[x]$. I have succeeded in showing that if $N=(0)$ then $p(x)$ is not divisible by the square of some polynomial $q(x) \in F[x]$. 
But how do I show that $p(x)$ is not divisible by the square of some polynomial $q(x) \in F[x]$ implies $N=(0)$?

---

Suppose $N\not =(0)$. Then there exist $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $a(x)\in F[x]$ such that $(a(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle)^k=\langle p(x)\rangle\implies a(x)^k \in  \langle p(x)\rangle$. This $k$ cannot be 1 as then $a(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle=\langle p(x)\rangle$. So $k\ge 2$.
 But I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Look at an irreducible factor decomposition of $a$ and $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's prove that

> If $N\ne 0$, then $p$ is divisible by the square of some polynomial.

Let $a$ be such that $a + (p) \ne 0$ but $(a+(p))^k = 0$.

In $F[x]$, this means that $p$ does not divide $a$ but $p$ divides $a^k$.

Since $p$ does not divide $a$, we have $v_q(p) > v_q(a)$, for some irreducible factor $q$ of $p$.
Here $v_q(t)$ is the exponent of $q$ in a factorization of $t$ into irreducibles.

Since $p$ does divide $a^k$, we have $v_q(p) \le v_q(a^k) = k v_q(a)$.

Therefore, $v_q(a) < v_q(p) \le k v_q(a)$ and so $v_q(a)$ cannot be zero, and we have $v_q(a) \ge 1$.

But then $v_q(p) > v_q(a) \ge 1$ and so $v_q(p) \ge 2$. This means that $q^2$ divides $p$.

Comment: In $F[x]$, this means that $p$ does not divide $a$ but $p$ divides $a^k$. Sorry, could you elaborate on this line?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copied the wrong part. I am unable to prove that "Since p does not divide a, we have vq(p)>vq(a), for some irreducible factor q of p."

Comment: @user96343, $b$ divides $a$ iff $v_q(b) \le v_q(a)$ for all irreducibles $q$. This follows from unique factorization.